# how to send node metrics to prometheus via api call's without using port?

Tags: prometheus

we have requirement to monitor the nodes with prometheus. but challenging part is, all these nodes are in the private networks and we can't expose ports to each other. and all these servers are sitting behind the jump hosts and we need prometheus servers on the public networks by getting metrics from private nodes and no ports expose. any possible solution?. And its fine to export the metrics and import them into grafana

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is pull based monitoring system, and it is generally recommended running Prometheus servers on the same network as the monitored instances.

If you consider exposing access to monitored nodes impossible (which without exposing endpoints through new or existing exposed port it is), then Prometheus is most likely wrong tool for this job.

You might try using [PushProx](https://github.com/prometheus-community/PushProx), to traverse network limitations. But I would strongly advise against it in favor of push based solutions like Graphite or InfluxDB.

---

You might have an idea about using Pushgateway, to convert Prometheus to push-based approach, but it is [very bad idea](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing). Don't do it.

Comment: Appreciated for the quick response. And i was thinking about push based mechanism but will it work without exposing ports on target nodes?. and architecture is like, need to access two jump servers to reach target nodes. and bad news is all these nodes are sits in the  private network including jump nodes. we need to create public node(monitor dashboard) and target nodes send metrics by going through two jump hosts. what is your opinion on this, is this possible to setup public monitoring dashboard of private nodes which are behind 2 jump nodes?

Comment: @SreekanthChityala, I have no clue what "jump node" mean in this context. But if you don't have direct access from your nodes to internet (monitoring server in public network), then you'll need some proxying/relaying solution.